# Java Media Framework - Start from beginning

Tags: java, frameworks, media, jmf

I am currently using Java Media Framework (JMF) [JMF LINK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) to play MP3 sounds for my program. I want to make my music loop, however - that is, play from the start when it is over - and I have used the following code in order to do so.

```
        player.addControllerListener(new ControllerListener() {
            public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent e) {
                if (e instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
                    System.out.println("MUSIC STOPPED! HELP!!!");
                    player.setMediaTime(new Time(0));
                }
            }
        });
```

The idea is, there is a listener on the mp3 player that sets the media time to the beginning (time of "0") when it hits the end. However, I am not too sure on how setting the media time works, because while the listener works for calling an event when the music ends, the music obviously isn't restarting and I'm left with awkward silence (and a debug message that says "MUSIC STOPPED! HELPP!!!"). Any tips to what I can do to start the music over from the start? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, my bad, I forgot to put in the updated code where I had the debug message inside of it. And no, there isn't an error being thrown - I think the problem is in the setMediaTime call, as it isn't doing what I would expect it to do (set the music at the initial position, 0:00).

Answer (score 1):

The error was that I had to stop and start the player around setting the media time to 0. Works like a charm now!